# How to check radio button by ID

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I wrote this code but not working, I cant see any wrong on this coad, can anyone help me to solve this problem.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1">Site 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2">Site 2<br>
<input type="submit" onclick="check()" value="Go">

<script>
    function check(){
        if(document.getElementById('radio1').checked){
            window.location="https://www.site1.com";
        }
        else if(document.getElementById('radio2').checked){
            window.location="https://www.site2.com";
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "not working."

Comment: you havent closed your function

Comment: Tip: Open your browsers console, this will display errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, for one thing, you're missing the closing `}` on the `check` function, so that's causing a syntax error you'd be able to see if you opened the web console; that means you have no `check` function. If you add the missing `}`, then your function should work.

Using the debugging tools built into your browser, including the web console, is a **fundamental skill** for writing code to run in browsers. (Using debuggers is a fundamental skill for programming, full stop.) Before doing anything else, I strongly recommend learning to use those tools, which not only include the console but a fully-featured debugger with which you can set breakpoints so the code stops and you can inspect variables and such, you can then step through the code line by line to see what's happening, etc.